# Terminal Server Plus (tsplus.net)

Tags: untagged

Has anyone used the "Terminal Server Plus" application listed at [www.tsplus.net](http://www.tsplus.net)? I've came across it in researching alternatives to RemoteApps from Microsoft. I can't find too much information on it, which is a bit of a worry - and wondered if any others had used it in their travels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've used it before, pretty simple to use, you could for example setup windows 7 as a terminal server. We've experimented with this after hearing about some companies doing a similar thing in order to share one really fast computer amongst 5 users.